# Why is half of one media query not working?

Tags: css, media-queries

I've had no issues with any media queries until I tried creating one for large desktop monitors. For some reason only some of the styles in the large device media query work and some don't. It seems the general styles are overriding only some of the large media query, I just don't know why.

I assumed it was in the wrong order and was being overridden, but no matter where I put it (above general styles, below smallest query, above big query), nothing changes. I then saw a suggestion that it needed more specificity, so I tried doing that as well as `!important`. Still nothing changes. I've checked for misplaced `;` and `{ }` but it's all correct.

These are my media queries in order:

```
General styles not in media query
/* styles that work */
@media only screen and (min-width: 2560px){ /* styles that HALF work */ }
@media only screen and (max-width: 1275px){ /* styles that work */ }
@media only screen and (max-width: 750px) { /* styles that work */ }
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) { /* styles that work */ }
@media only screen and (max-width: 375px) { /* styles that work */ }
```

**UPDATE: Code sample**

*PS: Idk who's downvoting everything but it isn't me.*

```
/* General styles that all work */
body {
    font-size: 1.8rem;
  }
h2{
    font-size: 4rem;
  }
h3{
   font-size: 3rem;
  }
.profilePic {
    width: 30rem;
    height: 30rem;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: var(--primary) 5px solid;
    padding: 1%;
  }
.typingEffect h1, .typingEffect p {
    font-size: 4.5rem;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

/* Large device media query where some work */
@media only screen and (min-width: 2560px){

body{
      font-size: 4rem; /* Works */
    }
h2{
    font-size: 9rem; /* Works */
    }
h3{
    font-size: 5rem; /* Works */
  }
.profilePic {
    width: 100rem; /* Doesn't work */
    height: 100rem; /* Doesn't work */
  }
.typingEffect h1, .typingEffect p {
    font-size: 10.5rem; /* WORKS FOR h1, NOT FOR p */
    padding: 5rem; /* WORKS FOR h1, NOT FOR p */
  }
}
```

```
<header>
  <img class="profilePic" src= "./images/orange-Avatar3.svg" alt="Avatar of me"/>
  <div class="typingEffect">
     <h1 class="name"> Hey, I'm Me</h1>
     <p class="tagline"><span className="typed-text"></span><span class="cursor">&nbsp;</span></p>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: The media query seems fine, probably you have some specificity problem.

Comment: Maybe showing rule-sets inside the first media query could be useful in order to receive valid answers.

Comment: xD he will not show any code instead he will downvote every answer. Anyway, it is a CSS Specificity problem. Add your code so we can tell you where the problem is occurring.

Comment: change min-width: 2560px to 1276px

Answer (score 0):

Ok buddy, I highly recommend going to the `Mobile-first design.` in order to avoid using `max-width`. Since order matters and you may end overruling some of the properties you wrote. Check this example out.

```css
div>header>h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: orange;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 2560px) {
  div>header>h1 {
    font-size: 150px;
    color: blueviolet;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1275px) {
  div>header>h1 {
    font-size: 100px;
    color: brown;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 750px) {
  div>header>h1 {
    font-size: 75px;
    color: yellowgreen;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  div>header>h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
    color: coral;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  div>header>h1 {
    font-size: 125px;
    color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header class="">
    <h1 class=""> Using Animation! </h1>
  </header>
</div>
```

As you can see every single query is working. But if you swap out the order problems will start to occur therefore you should always be careful when using `max-width` so you don't end up messing up your code.

Check out this snippet where I messed up the order.

```css
div>header>h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: orange;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 2560px) {
  div>header>h1 {
    font-size: 150px;
    color: blueviolet;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  div>header>h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
    color: coral;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  div>header>h1 {
    font-size: 125px;
    color: tomato;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1275px) {
  div>header>h1 {
    font-size: 100px;
    color: brown;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 750px) {
  div>header>h1 {
    font-size: 75px;
    color: yellowgreen;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header class="">
    <h1 class=""> Using Animation! </h1>
  </header>
</div>
```

In the above snippet, the following query didn't even work

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    div>header>h1 {
        font-size: 50px;
        color: coral;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 375px) {
    div>header>h1 {
        font-size: 125px;
        color: tomato;
    }
}
```

!! Since the code at the bottom is stronger in CSS you will find out the 750px breakpoint is working since it's at the bottom.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 750px)
```

and it is overruling the `breakpoints 600px and 375px` since they appeared before the 750px breakpoint which is at the bottom of the CSS file.

```
    @media only screen and (max-width: 600px)
    @media only screen and (max-width: 375px)
```

**

### I'm sure that your problem is just a CSS Specificity problem

**

That's why the best approach is to go `mobile-first and use min-width` since it is easier to care for and maintain. I hope my answer has given you a clear understanding of your problem and why your media were not working.

Comment: Well your explanation just confirms my media queries are correct. And I considered specificity and tried it, but I wouldn't think query code would need to over-specify it's original code since the query IS the specification.

Comment: Great. Then we need some code to work with in order to help you out. Can you post the CSS and HTML so we can dedicate what's not working probable and I will try my best to find out who's causing the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Use max-width instead of min-width for consistency

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 2560px){ /* styles that HALF work */ }
@media only screen and (max-width: 1275px){ /* styles that work */ }
@media only screen and (max-width: 750px) { /* styles that work */ }
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) { /* styles that work */ }
@media only screen and (max-width: 375px) { /* styles that work */ }
```

Comment: max-width stops it at 2560, I need it to start at 2560

Answer (score -1):

use min-width instead max-width
when using max-width to this way css media query can't understand your query

When your page is 600px, it is compatible with almost all media queries

bestway:

```css
/* styles that work */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1275px){ /* styles that HALF work */ } 
@media only screen and (min-width: 751px){ /* styles that work */ }
@media only screen and (min-width: 601px) { /* styles that work */ }
@media only screen and (min-width: 376px) { /* styles that work */ }
@media only screen and (max-width: 375px) { /* styles that work */ }
```

Comment: Adjusting mins and maxes created the same issue, just opposite. Now small mobile styles don't work. This does confirm it has something to do with the queries and not the styles though, so that's progress.

Comment: when your screensize =375
media only screen and (min-width: 2560px) => false,
media only screen and (max-width: 1275px)=> True,  
media only screen and (max-width: 750px) => True,
media only screen and (max-width: 600px) => True,
media only screen and (max-width: 375px) => True